# I'm trying to create a search filter using multiple <select> elements

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

I'm trying to create a search filter using multiple  elements to show/hide search results on selection. The search results should show or hide according to value of , and the data is being extracted from mysqli db. It works fine when mysqli table contains only 1 result but when I insert more data on the table, the results doesn't display!

Screenshot of the database:

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#result_shobra').hide();
    $('#result_nasrcity').hide();
    $('#result_dokki').hide();
    
    $("#searchBtnDistrict").click(function(){
        
        if($('#district').val() == 'nasrcity') {
            $('.resultDiv').hide();         
            $('#result_nasrcity').show();
            location.href='#result_nasrcity';
            
        } 
        
        else {
        
        if($('#district').val() == 'dokki') {
            $('.resultDiv').hide();
            $('#result_dokki').show();
            location.href='#result_dokki';
        }   
            
        if($('#district').val() == 'shobra') {
            $('.resultDiv').hide();
            $('#result_shobra').show();
            location.href='#result_shobra';
        }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
    <!-- Search Results -->
    <div id="result_shobra" class="resultDiv">
    <?php
    $res = mysqli_query($link,"select * from coaches where district='shobra' AND active='yes'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {?>
    <?php $coach_image = $row["ad_image"]; ?>
    <?php $profile = $row["public_url"]; ?>
    <?php $coach_name = $row["coach_name"]; ?>
    <?php $coach_desc = $row["coach_desc"]; ?>
    <?php
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";?>
    <div class="result">
    <center>
    <a href="<?php echo $profile; ?>">
    <img class="coach_image" src="<?php echo $coach_image; ?>" height="120" width="30%">
    </a>
    <p style="padding:20px;width:100%;font-size:1em;color:white;border-bottom: 0.5px solid #3a3a3a;">
    <?php echo $coach_name; ?>
    <br>
    <span class="coach_desc">
    <?php echo $coach_desc; }?>
    </span>
    </p>
    </center>
    </div>
    <?php echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
    </div>

    <div id="result_nasrcity" class="resultDiv">
    <?php
    $res = mysqli_query($link,"select * from coaches where district='nasrcity' AND active='yes'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {?>
    <?php $coach_image = $row["ad_image"]; ?>
    <?php $profile = $row["public_url"]; ?>
    <?php $coach_name = $row["coach_name"]; ?>
    <?php $coach_desc = $row["coach_desc"]; ?>
    <?php
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";?>
    <div class="result">
    <center>
    <a href="<?php echo $profile; ?>">
    <img class="coach_image" src="<?php echo $coach_image; ?>" height="120" width="30%">
    </a>
    <p style="padding:20px;width:100%;font-size:1em;color:white;border-bottom: 0.5px solid #3a3a3a;">
    <?php echo $coach_name; ?>
    <br>
    <span class="coach_desc">
    <?php echo $coach_desc; }?>
    </span>
    </p>
    </center>
    </div>
    <?php echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
    </div>

    <div id="result_dokki" class="resultDiv">
    <?php
    $res = mysqli_query($link,"select * from coaches where district='dokki' AND active='yes'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {?>
    <?php $coach_image = $row["ad_image"]; ?>
    <?php $profile = $row["public_url"]; ?>
    <?php $coach_name = $row["coach_name"]; ?>
    <?php $coach_desc = $row["coach_desc"]; ?>
    <?php
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";?>
    <div class="result">
    <center>
    <a href="<?php echo $profile; ?>">
    <img class="coach_image" src="<?php echo $coach_image; ?>" height="120" width="30%">
    </a>
    <p style="padding:20px;width:100%;font-size:1em;color:white;border-bottom: 0.5px solid #3a3a3a;">
    <?php echo $coach_name; ?>
    <br>
    <span class="coach_desc">
    <?php echo $coach_desc; }?>
    </span>
    </p>
    </center>
    </div>
    <?php echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Actually, you are fetching all the data from the database and showing/hiding the div. This will not be efficient or can't be used for production. What you should do is pass the selected element to server side and depending upon the selected value run the query and output the result.

Comment: Here is a similar example: https://phppot.com/php/multi-select-dropdown-filter-in-php-with-database-search/

Comment: That was helpful. The example you sent me made the idea clear enough. Thanks!